# Unable to insert in DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, insert

**PHP code:**

```
session_start();

include'include/connect.php';
include'include/header.php';

if(isset($_POST["helpline"])) {      
  $feedback=$_POST['feedback'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];

  {
    $sql= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO helpcenter set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',feedback='".$feedback."',email='".$email."'");
  }

  if($stmt) {
    echo "hello world";
  }
}
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email...">
  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <textarea id="subject" name="feedback" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:160px"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="butn" name="helpline">POST</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to insert data into a mysql database. I can't find out what wrong I'm doing here.

Comment: it doesn't output Hello world or it doesn't add to the database at all?

Comment: @KristjanKica May i know reason

Comment: It doesnt matter. You have the syntax of Insert wrong. See the answers

Comment: Your html form does not specify action. change `<form action="your_php_file.php" method="post">`.

Comment: @hcheung it doesnt need to, if its in the same file.

Comment: @KristjanKica yes we use set instead of values i have done many times

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Is `id` presernt in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @Yogesh no error, problem with insert into db

Comment: Can you see what is the insert statement after replacing values?

Answer (score -2):

Please check you SQL syntax.

Your insert should be something like :

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO helpcenter (uid, feedback, email) VALUES  (".$_SESSION['id'].", ".$feedback.", ".$email.")";
```